# How can I set session timeout so that it never expires?

Tags: java, session, servlets

How can I set session timeout so that it never expires? It's for a Java EE web application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify a negative time.

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

The benefit is however questionable. The webapp will leak memory away on long term. Think twice before you do this.

Comment: Not to mention the potential security holes. Think three times.

Comment: Yes, it would give the hacker a lot more room to (brute)force a session fixation attack.

Comment: If you want to do it from java side 
       request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

Comment: Commentators, could you, please, elaborate on your theseses?  I can sniff your cookies and do with your session whatever I want. How session expiration time makes it magically more secure? What security holes are you speaking about? https://security.stackexchange.com/q/174337

Comment: @Evgeni: brute force costs time. This is basically giving away unlimited time to successfully perform one.