# Set the session-timeout never expires in java / struts1.x

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, web.xml

How to set the session timeout never expires in struts1.x

```
web.xml
-------

        <session-config>
         <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
```

Comment: why would you want to do it ?

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536928/how-can-i-set-session-timeout-so-that-it-never-expires

Comment: @jigar joshi, I set the session timeout in 24 hrs , but my client never logout the system, in that time i found the NullPointerExceptions in my logs

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `-1`

```
    <session-config>
         <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

**Warning:**

This is not recommended to set session expiration infinite.

But, you should  add the full details of why you are doing this, So that a proper solution you'l get.

Comment: @suresh atta , the session-timeout "-1" gives some memmory leaks

Comment: @chakri Why you are trying to do this ? That is what I said in my post. Not at all recommended.

Comment: @suresh atta, I set the session timeout 24 hrs, but my client never logout the system, after 24 hrs session was expired, in that time i found the NullPointerExceptions in my logs

Comment: @chakri show the stacktraces  and explain the complete problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

paste below code in your `web.xml`

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

You can use "-1" where the session never expires. Since you do not know how much time it will take for the thread to complete.

**Note**: Please avoid to use infinite session timeout, it results to some memory leaks.