# servlet session-timeout(0) is not working

Tags: java, session, servlets, timeout

I want to set the session to not expire. I set the session-config in web.xml.

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

I don't set the session.setMaxInactiveInterval, so the session-config should be executed firstly. But this is not working.I set the session JDBCStore in context.xml below. I think it causes the problem. When I set session-timeout to 0 or -1, I can find that the max_inactive is -60 in database.Sometimes, I can't find the data in database. I'm very confused.

```
  <Manager className="PersistentManager"
   saveOnRestart="true"
   maxActiveSession="-1"
   minIdleSwap="0"
   maxIdleSwap="30"
   maxIdleBackup="0"> 
    <Store className="JDBCStore"
      driverName="Driver" 
      connectionURL="mysql://localhost?user;password" 
      sessionTable="cache_session" 
      sessionIdCol="session_id" 
      sessionDataCol="data" 
      sessionValidCol="session_valid" 
      sessionMaxInactiveCol="max_inactive" 
      sessionLastAccessedCol="last_access"
      sessionAppCol="application_name" 
      checkInterval="60" 
      debug="99" />
 </Manager>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set session timeout so that it never expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536928/how-can-i-set-session-timeout-so-that-it-never-expires)